# Driver for Startech USB2DVIE2

Tags: drivers

Is there a Linux driver for Startech USB2DVIE2?  It is necessary to support a 2nd monitor.  I can get this set-up to work in Windows 10 but I am trying to migrate to Linux Mint.
I have looked on the Startech website and they don't supply a driver.

Answer (score 0):

The [datasheet](https://www.startech.com/media/products/USB2DVIE2/PDFs/USB2DVIE2_Datasheet.pdf) lists USB2DVIE2 as using a "Trigger" chipset. As far as I could find, there is currently no Linux driver for any any Trigger video hardware.

(The other products listed in the datasheet currently have *some* Linux support – there is a native Linux driver for DisplayLink-based devices (drm/udl and udlfb), and there is a poor external driver for Fresco-based devices which only works with 4-year-old kernels.)

Comment: I have decided to buy a device that uses a DisplayLink chip.  DisplayLink say that they support Ubut

Comment: https://www.displaylink.com/downloads/ubuntu      on their website and even offer help to install the driver.  Joe